# Importing two shared libraries which uses C++ streams into python results in corrupted output

Tags: python, c++, gcc, boost

I've been looking into a particularly nasty bug - wanted to find out from the community if this is just me being stupid (entirely possible) or is there something odd happening.

So, to replicate the problem, you need GCC 5.3 and boost 1.60.

First pyt.cpp -> which compiles to libpyt.so

```
/*
 * This inclusion should be put at the beginning.  It will include <Python.h>.
 */
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

/*
 * This is the C++ function we write and want to expose to Python.
 */
const std::string hello1(const std::string& name) {
  std::ostringstream str;
  str << "Hello: " << name << ", here is a number: " << 10 << std::endl;
  return str.str();
}

/*
 * This is a macro Boost.Python provides to signify a Python extension module.
 */
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libpyt) {
    // An established convention for using boost.python.
     using namespace boost::python;

    // Expose the function hello2().
    def("hello1", hello1);
}
```

Second pyto.cpp -> which compiles to libpyto.so

```
/*
 * This inclusion should be put at the beginning.  It will include <Python.h>.
 */
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

/*
 * This is the C++ function we write and want to expose to Python.
 */
const std::string hello2(const std::string& name) {
  std::ostringstream str;
  str << "Hello: " << name << ", here is a number: " << 10 << std::endl;
  return str.str();
}

/*
 * This is a macro Boost.Python provides to signify a Python extension module.
 */
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libpyto) {
    // An established convention for using boost.python.
     using namespace boost::python;

    // Expose the function hello2().
    def("hello2", hello2);
}
```

I compiled using the following:

```
/usr/local/gcc5_3_0/bin/g++ -std=c++14 pyt.cpp -fPIC -shared -o libpyt.so -I /usr/local/boost1_60_0_gcc5_3_0/include/ -I /usr/include/python2.7/ -L /usr/local/boost1_60_0_gcc5_3_0/lib64/ -Wl,-Bstatic -l boost_python.pic -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread -lpython2.7 -ldl -lrt -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc

/usr/local/gcc5_3_0/bin/g++ -std=c++14 pyto.cpp -fPIC -shared -o libpyto.so -I /usr/local/boost1_60_0_gcc5_3_0/include/ -I /usr/include/python2.7/ -L /usr/local/boost1_60_0_gcc5_3_0/lib64/ -Wl,-Bstatic -l boost_python.pic -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread -lpython2.7 -ldl -lrt -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
```

(ignore the `.pic` extension for the boost library, it's just a static library with objects that were compiled with `-fPIC` - using this same compiler.)

Now, I simply import them into python, and call the hello1/2 functions:

```
bash-4.2$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 15 2016, 22:37:39) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libpyt
>>> import libpyto
>>> libpyto.hello2("hello");
'Hello: hello, here is a number: 10\n'
>>> libpyt.hello1("hello");
'Hello: hello, here is a number: '  <<<!!! What???
>>> 
bash-4.2$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 15 2016, 22:37:39) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libpyto
>>> import libpyt
>>> libpyt.hello1("Hello")
'Hello: Hello, here is a number: 10\n'
>>> libpyto.hello2("Hello") 
'Hello: Hello, here is a number: '  <<<!!! What???
```

As you can see, irrespective of the order of import, the second hello function fails to generate the output correctly. So my question is, why is the streaming out of the integer value failing for the second call?

**EDIT:** One more data point, enabling exceptions on the streams, results in a `std::bad_cast` being thrown on the second call.

Comment: How specifically is the output wrong? It's not clear or obvious

Comment: @MrJLP, it's missing the ` 10\n` . This is how I know the stream is some how corrupted, it's not streaming out the integer 10.

Comment: I'm curious what happens if you assign `int val = 10` and then print out `val` if the problem still happens. Might be a boost bug. BTW I'd recommend stating clearly the actual problem at the top of your question.

Comment: @MrJLP, it shouldn't make any difference (and it doesn't btw,) as I said, for the two compilers, I'm actually using two different versions of boost. I'd imagine such an issue would have been caught by now - if it was there..

Comment: Mixing libraries with ABI differences and/or ODR violations is undefined behaviour

Comment: @sehe, so after my edit2, I'm actually not mixing ABIs (I initially thought this might be the problem as well) However - that does not appear to be the case. ODR - well that's a different thing, I guess you could argue that `hello()` breaks it.. but they are in two different "modules"?

Comment: You're still referring to different versions of libraries. You're not very clear on which. But if there's any difference in lib/version/flags then yes calling across modules can easily invoke UB

Comment: Basically, the same code is compiled into two different libraries - actually, I changed the function names to be `hello1()` and `hello2()`, they are compiled by the same compiler (5.3 and boost 1.60) into two libs (libpyt.so and libpyto.so) which are then both imported - the second call fails - it appears due to an issue with `std::locale` instantiation. I'm not sure - where I'm breaking ABI or ODR?

Comment: Step back. Cool down. Remove everything built. Sleep on it. Wake up. Make sure everything from the old build is gone.  Have a nice breakfast. I'd suggest sausage and eggs. Look at the birds in the park. Make a new build.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe - Hahaha... I did already - had a long walk by the lake and multiple ice creams - still no luck.. :) I'm sure I'm doing something stupid.. but not entirely sure what..

Comment: Okay - fixed the question - removed all the confusion around compilers and boost versions, all settings are same, two different modules, imported into python - both uses streams, somehow the second call fails...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Boost.Python, but what happens if hello1 and hello2 return char* instead of std::string?

Comment: @BorkoJandras, unfortunately the problem is *before* it gets to the return, the streaming out of the integer value fails (infact, if you enable exceptions on the `ostringstream`, for some strange reason it throws a `std::bad_cast`!)

Comment: So you have two dynamic libraries (Python modules), each linked with a static libstdc++ and with static boost library that was in turned linked with a static libstdc++?

Comment: @BorkoJandras the boost library is not statically linked to anything, it's a *static* library (`.a`) which has objects which where compiled with `-fPIC` (in our production environment, we don't want to have boost installed, so rather statically link it where possible..)

Comment: @Nim Maybe error message spewed out by valgrind will steer you in the right direction.

Comment: @BorkoJandras, first thing I tried - unfortunately valgrind doesn't say anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146806/discussion-between-borko-jandras-and-nim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay - so the problem is simple to resolve in the end. The issue stems from `-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc`. It appears that you cannot import multiple modules into python which have libstdc++ and libgcc statically linked.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix multiple copies of Boost.Python in the same process. If you do, you get two type registries, and only one will be found and used.

Solution: use Boost.Python as a shared library, shared between your two Python module shared objects.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the issue.